# Titanium Ti.GeoLocation.forwardGeocoder() is not converting Non US address to lat and long values

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

`Ti.GeoLocation.forwardGeocoder()` is not converting Non US address to lat and long values.

sample code below.

```
Ti.GeoLocation.forwardGeocoder('Hyderabad, India', function(e){
var lat = e.latitude;
var long = e.longitude;
});
```

with this code we are getting lat and long values are undefined.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to get US addresses, and everywhere else in the world (that Google can find) and display the Long/Lat on a titanium Map.

The code below uses the string variable: myAddress

```
var myAddress = address + ','+ city + ',' + postal + ',' + country //'Vieux Port, Montreal, Quebec, H2X3R4, Canada'
var xhrGeocode = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient();
xhrGeocode.setTimeout(120000);
xhrGeocode.onerror = function (e) {
    alert('Google couldn\'t find the address... check your address');
};
xhrGeocode.onload = function (e) {
    var response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    if (response.status == 'OK' && response.results != undefined && response.results.length > 0) {
        longitude = response.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
        latitude = response.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
    }
};
var urlMapRequest = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + myAddress.replace(/ /g, '+');
urlMapRequest += "&sensor=" + (Ti.Geolocation.locationServicesEnabled == true);
xhrGeocode.open("GET", urlMapRequest);
xhrGeocode.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
xhrGeocode.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            var addrReq = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
            var addrUrl = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=true&address="+ query;
            addrReq.open("GET",addrUrl);
            addrReq.send(null);


            addrReq.onload = function()
            {
                 var response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

                  if(response.status == "OK"){



                    LT.Customlat=response.results[0].geometry.location.lat; 
                    LT.Customlon=response.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
```

}

Answer (score -1):

you will need to roll your own solution using google REST APIs, the underlying Titanium API does not support non-us addresses

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.